# Why my javascript variable referencing a function stay unchanged even after I overload the referenced function?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem of understanding how javascript works, and I can't find a correct explanation, perhaps you could help me.

Assuming the following code :

```
// aFunction references console.error
var aFunction = console.error;

// Assign a new property to aFunction
// As aFunction references console.error it will have the property too
aFunction.callCount = 0;

aFunction.hasOwnProperty("callCount");        //true
console.error.hasOwnProperty("callCount");    //true

// Overload console.error (why is not the purpose)
console.error = function() {}

console.dir(aFunction);     //VM807:2 function log() { [native code] }
console.dir(console.error); //VM808:2 function () {}
```

Why aFunction still references the original console.error ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent; is it "aFunction" or "myFun"? "callCount" or "_someProperty"?

Answer (score 3):

When you set a variable to a reference to an object (a function, in this case), it gets a *copy* of that reference value. Subsequent changes to other variables or object properties that share that reference value won't have any effect on the copy you made.

It should be clear what's going on here, right?

```
var a = 2;
var b = a;
console.log(b); // 2
a = 3;
console.log(b); // still 2
```

Object references work the same way:

```
var a = { hello: "world" };
var b = a;
console.log(b.hello); // world
a = { hello: "goodbye" };
console.log(b.hello); // still world
```

Variable `a` got a new value, but that didn't affect `b` at all. The assignment operator `=` makes copies of values. There's no way to make one JavaScript variable (object property) be an alias for another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The concept of reference in JavaScript is stil a bit fuzzy to me, maybe because of my C++ background.